# How to deal with categorical features having large number of levels in it

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am working on a data set in R having dimensions

```
dim(adData)
[1] 15844717       11
```

Out of 11 features,

one feature is having 273596(random integers used as id) unique values out of 15844717.

second feature is having 884353(random integers used as id) unique values out of 15844717.

My confusion is whether to convert them into factors or not because categorical variables with large number of levels will create a problem at the time of modelling or please suggest how to treat them.

I am new to Data Science and never worked on large data sets before.

Answer (score 1):

~300k categories for one variable is sure to cause computational issues.  I would first take a step back and examine the nature of this variable and its relevance to the prediction at hand.  Without knowing the source of the data, it is hard to give specific advice.

If it is truly a categorical variable, it would be silly to leave the ids as numeric variables since the scale and order of the ids are likely meaningless.

**Is it possible to group the levels into fewer but still meaningful categories?**

Example 1:  If the ids were zipcodes in the United States, there are potentially 40,000 unique values.  These can be grouped into states or regions, reducing the number of levels to 50 or fewer.

Example 2:  If the ids were product ids from an e-commerce site, they could be grouped by product category or sub-category.  There would be much fewer distinct values to work with.

Another option is to examine the relative frequency of each category.  If there are a few very common categories, with thousands of rare categories, you leave the common levels in tact and group the rare levels into an 'other' category.

Comment: Data is of e-commerce site. One of the feature is advertisement site name and other is offer id. I ll try to combine them according to the relative frequency.